# onClick xml dont working in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

[onClick  working in java but do not working in kotlin . i try add 
android:clickable="true" and android:onClick="test" but not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpUlr.png)

Comment: did you define method in source? if yes post your code also

Comment: Please post your code as text, along with the error message you're getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a function first then it will work. Create a method (function) name with **test()** and you can implement onclick.

Answer (score 0):

You have implement test function create Activity or Fragment

example:

```
 fun test(){
    Toast.makeText(this,"test",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

}